# How to get SQLite to jump to different TextView?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two TextViews in my MainActivity and I am able to change the first TextView to my high score but I am not able to change to the second TextView to the next high score (I'm making a game). The code I am messing with is in the updateDatabase() method in DBHandler class.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//sqlite
//EditText input;
//first high score
static TextView productText;
static TextView productText2;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //sqlite
    //input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_ID);
    productText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    productText2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //GameScreen gameScreen = new GameScreen();
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    dbHandler.updateDatabase();
}

public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

GameActivity

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity {

private TextView time;
private ImageButton start;
private ImageButton gameButton;
private ImageButton button2;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
public static int count = 0;
public static int countPass = 0;
public String countPassString = "";
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
//MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cancel();
    }
};




private View.OnClickListener btnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.start_ID:
                start();
                break;
            case R.id.gameButton_ID:
                gameButton();
                break;
            case R.id.button2_ID:
                button2();
                break;
        }

    }


};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);


    start = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.start_ID);
    start.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    gameButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gameButton_ID);
    gameButton.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
    button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2_ID);
    button2.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);

    button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

public void start(){

    count = 0;
    start.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    time.setText("100");
    //this doesnt work and makes app crash when you hit start button

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(100 * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millsUntilFinished){
            time.setText("" + millsUntilFinished / 1000);

            //turns textview string to int
            int foo = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());

            if(foo == 93) {
                time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if(foo == 97) {
                gameButton.animate().translationX(200).setDuration(5000).start(); // move away
            }
            else if(foo == 90){
                gameButton.animate().translationY(200).setDuration(5000).start(); // move away
            }

            if(foo  % 2 == 0){

                handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            time.setText("Done !");

            //need to check if score will reset if you win the game

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You scored " + count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            gameButton.clearAnimation();
            gameButton.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(500).start(); //move back
            gameButton.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500).start(); //move back
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
}

private void cancel(){
    if(countDownTimer != null){
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;
        start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gameButton.clearAnimation();
        gameButton.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(500).start(); //move back
        gameButton.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500).start(); //move back
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //holds score at end of game
        countPass = count;
        //reset score for new game
        count = 0;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You scored " + countPass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        countPassString = Integer.toString(countPass);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        //mainActivity.productText.setText(countPassString);
        dbHandler.addButtonClicked(countPassString);
    }
}

private void gameButton(){


    int foo = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());

    if(foo  % 2 == 0 ) {
        final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "+1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        // makes +1 toast half a second
        Handler gameButtonToastHandler = new Handler();
        gameButtonToastHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toast.cancel();
            }
        }, 500);

        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
        ++count;
    }
    else{
        cancel();
    }
}

private void button2(){
    cancel();
}
```

}

DBHandler

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Products product){
    SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//code coming from MainActivity
public void addButtonClicked(String highscore1){
    Products product = new Products(highscore1);
    addProduct(product);
    updateDatabase();
}

//code coming from MainActivity
public void updateDatabase(){
    if(MainActivity.productText.toString() == ""){
        String dbString = databaseToString();
        MainActivity.productText.setText(dbString);
    }
    else if(MainActivity.productText2.toString() == "2:"){
        String dbString = databaseToString();
        MainActivity.productText2.setText(dbString);
    }
    else{
        String dbString = databaseToString();
        MainActivity.productText.setText(dbString);
    }

}

//delete a product from the database
public void deleteProduct(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";" );
}


//print out the database as a string
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";


    //Cursor point to location in your results

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }


    db.close();
    return dbString;

}
```

}

Products

```
public class Products {
private int _id;
private String _productname;

public Products(){

}

public Products(String productname){
    this._productname = productname;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void set_productname(String _productname) {
    this._productname = _productname;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String get_productname() {
    return _productname;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be manipulating UI components from a SQLiteOpenHelper. Leave this helper with **JUST** database operations that you might have. On your activity, grab the cursor of the of below query

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";
```

And update your UI.

Remember not doing that on the main UI thread. Make use of [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "grab cursor of the of below query"?